# How to intuitively prove a bound for the result of this expression?

Tags: real-analysis

In A Book of Abstract Algebra by Charles Pinter, 2nd edition, chapter 2, exercise A4, we are asked to show that, if $x$ and $y$ are chosen from the open interval $(-1, 1)$, then the value of

$$\frac{x + y}{xy + 1}$$

will also be in that interval. I am struggling to do this. I think I have a partial solution:

> Suppose $x$ and $y$ are both positive. Then the numerator and denominator are both positive, and the numerator will be less than the denominator by the following reasoning. Begin with the quantity $x + 1$. In order to achieve the value of the numerator, we multiply the $1$ in this expression by $y$, which subtracts $1(1-y)$ from the final value. In order to achieve the value of the denominator, we multiply the $x$ by $y$, which subtracts $x(1-y)$ from the final value. More succinctly:
>
> $$x + y = x + 1 - 1(1-y)$$
> $$xy + 1 = x + 1 - x(1-y)$$
>
> Since $x < 1$, we are subtracting a greater amount from the former expression. So, the numerator is less than the denominator. Nearly analogous reasoning applies to the case where $x$ and $y$ are both negative.

However, I'm not sure what to do about the case where $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs. I'm fairly happy with the intuitiveness of the argument laid out above. Is there any way to solve the whole problem in a similarly intuitive fashion, i.e. without resorting to separating the problem into four cases and using purely algebraic artifices to solve them?

Comment: This is the "Relativistic Velocity Addition" rule when "$c=1$". With the intuition of first postulate of Relativity this is always less than $<1$ for $x,y \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: I've voted to migrate

Comment: Would the downvoter explain their vote please? If the reason is that the question should be migrated, is there a way I can do that?

Comment: "A Book of Abstract Algebra" is not very descriptive.  Could you give a more detailed reference, e.g., an author?

Comment: @LSpice I'm pretty sure there's only one book by that title, but I've added the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1 + x y$ is positive for all $x, y \in (-1, 1)$; so, since our function is odd in $(x, y)$ and hence takes values in $(-1, 1)$ if it takes values in $(-\infty, 1)$, it suffices to show that $x + y$ is strictly less than $1 + x y$.  This is true because $1 + x y - x - y = (1 - x)(1 - y)$ is strictly positive when $x$ and $y$ are both strictly less than $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does it mean for a function to be odd in two variables like that? And why does it imply that its values being in (-inf, 1) means its values will be in (-1, 1)?

Comment: [It](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3792944/how-to-intuitively-prove-a-bound-for-the-result-of-this-expression/3793010#comment7816432_3793010) means that $f(-x, -y) = -f(x, y)$.  Thus, if *all* values of $f$ are in $(-\infty, 1)$, then also $f(x, y) = -f(-x, -y) \in -(-\infty, 1) = (-1, \infty)$ for all $(x, y) \in (-1, 1)^2$.  (Interval notation and ordered-pair notation don't play together so nicely—sorry!)

Answer (score 2):

One proof uses the addition formula for the hyperbolical tangent function:

$$\tanh(a+b)=\frac{\tanh(a)+\tanh(b)}{1+ \tanh(a)\tanh(b)}$$

where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

$\tanh$ maps from $\mathbb{R}$ surjectively onto $(-1,1)$. Hence for any $x,y \in (-1,1)$ there exists $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x=\tanh(a)$ and $y=\tanh(b)$ which gives

$$\frac{x+y}{xy+1}=\frac{\tanh(a)+\tanh(b)}{1+ \tanh(a)\tanh(b)}=\tanh(a+b)\in(-1,1).$$

Comment: You'd probably better be a little careful allowing $x, y \in [-1, 1]$, in case $x = 1$ and $y = -1$.

Comment: @LSpice True, thank you. I had actually misread the question and thought it was for the closed interval which it actually does make sense except for $xy=-1$ as you rightly point out. I think I'll just correct my answer to make the interval closed.

Comment: I mean open :-)

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate wrt (wlog) $x$ to show that it's increasing in $x$ when $|y| < 1$; then evaluate at $x=-1$ and at $x=1$ to demonstrate the bound.